# Redirect requests via routes sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, sails.js

I would like to have a sub part in my application:
For instance, all requests send to `www.example.com/backoffice/user` should be redirected in my `BackofficeUserController.js`.

I ue sails.js, I know I have to do that with the config/routes.js, I just don't know how.

I tried this:

```
'/backoffice/:controller/:action?': {
    controller    : 'backoffice' + ':controller',
    action        : ':action'
}
```

But it doesn't works. Any idea?
The doc doesn't explains too much about dynamic routes. http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a decent use-case for nested controllers.  If you do `sails generate controller backoffice/user`, you'll end up with a `controllers/backoffice/userController.js` file corresponding to a controller class called `Backoffice/UserController`.  All requests to `/backoffice/user/:action` will then be automatically routed to that controller.

Comment: You meant that if I create controllers inside backoffice they will be used automatically? Do I need to do it in command line?

Comment: I actually tried that in first place, before write this message and it didn't work. I tried again here (0.9.8) and it doesn't, still. I tried using a controller generated in command line but still not working.

Comment: And my config/routes.js doesn't contains anything more than the '/' route.

Comment: You don't need to use the command line; you can create the `backoffice` folder yourself and put `userController.js` inside it.  Just know that if you want to refer to the controller in `config/route.js`, the class name is `backoffice/usercontroller`

Comment: Confirmed working in v0.9.8 too.  Fixed original answer to correct name of generated file (it's `userController.js`, not `user.js`) and the capital 'C' is meaningful.  Again, you don't have to use the generator, just make sure you name the files correctly!

Comment: Still trying, still 404. I used the good name (with 'Controller.js' part). Tried on existing controller, tried with a new one... Do you have the source code? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Okay, it works. Thanks. That was because my 'test' function didn't use parameters. It was not found if req and res wasn't used as parameters! EDIT/ Well, or something else, maybe I was too quick, but that's still really weird... I'll try to make it work on my real controllers...

Comment: Honnestly, it's getting messy. I created /test/testController.js with a test method that req.send('test') and it works. I create a /test/applicationController.js with the same, it took several restart server to work... I'm thinking... maybe that's because I don't use sails lift but node app.js !

Comment: FOUND! The word 'backoffice' is reserved by sails or something, that was because of the name of the folder, I renamed it to 'back' and it worked directely. I was going crazy...

Comment: Edit: Finally, no dark magic. That didn't work because I had a api/controller/backofficeController.js and the route was linked to it and not to the backoffice folder!

Answer (score 1):

All captured params get passed to the controller's action method on your request object. Maybe you should be more explicit when defining your routes or use your UserController as a proxy.

You could have backoffice users?

```
'/user/backoffice': 'UserController.backoffice'
```

or having a backoffice controller handle user requests

```
'/backoffice/user/:id': 'BackofficeController.user'
```

or (i'm not sure if controllers are global but you could require the controller from another controller and use its methods inside UserController)

```
module.exports = {
  '/backoffice/user/:id': 'UserController.backoffice'
};
```

and then in your UserController

```
var BackofficeController = require('./BackofficeController');

module.exports = {
  user: function(req, res) {
   // Do something using BackOffice methods conditionally?
  }
};
```

Many ways to achieve the same result. Not sure what the best approach is since I haven't run into this personally. But I would suggest sticking with Sailsjs conventions.